# Why does the label for the dijit.form.radiobutton not show up?

Tags: dojo, dijit.form

I have this code but the label does not show up:

```
            var radioOne = new RadioButton({
                label: "Current",
                style: "margin-left:10px",
                checked: true
            }).placeAt(userDiv);
```

Do I have to do a domCreate of an actual label tag?

Answer (score 2):

I've gone ahead and am using this to create the label tag.

```
            var label = domConstruct.create("label", {
                for: "Previous",
                style: "margin-left:5px",
                innerHTML: "Previous"
            }, userDiv);
```

this does work but seems this should be included in the RadioButton widget.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you do. This was from the dojo documentations:

Script:

```
var radioOne = new RadioButton({
            checked: true,
            value: "tea",
            name: "drink",
        }, "radioOne");
```

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="drink" id="radioOne" checked value="tea"/> <label for="radioOne">Tea</label>
```

Comment: I have seen that from the docs already but they show a combined solution showing both declarative and programmatic and don't really show how to handle the label aspect programmatically. So are you saying that to do this programmatically you have to do a create of a label tag?

Comment: It seems so. Looking at the JS and template files (checkBox) for radioButton, it doesn't have a place for label.

Comment: You can always make your own widget using a template that has a label if you need to. It would probably be only a few lines of code. A few lines to declare inheriting RadioButton. And two lines for the template.